# Is it possible to get the favorites list from the browser?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

Is it possible to read a user's favorites list using asp.net?

Answer (score 5):

This would violate the visitors privacy. You would need a browser component that they installed locally to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is technically a server side technology... it does allow you to output html and javascript, but to be more concise your question should read:

"Is it possible to read a user's favorites (bookmarks) via javascript?"

Since you need a client side script to do this.

And the answer to that question, unfortunately for you, is no.

Answer (score 0):

God, I hope not. And if so they need to fix that immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, ASP.net is on the server side not on client side so i m sure it's impossible to do it without a plugin (i m even not sure you can do it using a javascript), on firefox some social network provide specific plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Yes.

Is it possible without the user having to accept a component install? No.

Is it possible using only ASP.NET without running code on the client? No.

You would have to create something like an ActiveX component or a Java applet that you run in the browser. The component would have to check for different browsers and different versions of each browser to know where the favorites would be stored. Some browsers may store them in such a way that it's practically impossible to read them.